# How to set a run/debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA using a Jar file?

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, intellij-idea, jar

Thanks for welcoming me to the community!

I'd like to get some help regarding Run/Debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA. We use a .jar file and I need to setup a run configuration in my IDE. I go to **Run>Edit Configurations>JAR Application** and then the various options pop up.
I have the .jar file but wish to know which properties need to be set in which fields. We use a .bat file to startup the .jar and I'm posting the same below.

Could someone please look at the start.bat file and tell me what I need to be feeding into my Run/Debug options?

```
java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -Xmx1200m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M  -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=30306,suspend=n -jar my-sample-jar.jar -gui
```

Here's what I see in my IntelliJ window :

[image]

Besides, I used Maven to build up the project in IntelliJ (by importing the .pom file).
Appreciate your valuable feedback, looking forward to contributing here!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Welcome Manan!  You should be able to create a target for the jar application in IntelliJ by following these steps.

> EDIT: Upon initially reading your question I didn't see you already
>   had the steps for creating a new jar configuration, but I'll leave the
>   images here for future readers.

First, open your run/debug configurations in the top right:

[image]

Then create a new configuration with the plus:

[image]

Enter the appropriate information for the jar.  I've edited and shown what you should use. (Comments aren't valid and for demonstration)

[image]

You can run or debug the configuration by selecting from the dropdown and selecting the required button.  ctrl-d debugs and ctrl-r runs by default.

[image]

**To expand upon what you should enter for the fields** (see the image above for your exact configuration):

- Path to jar: This is the file path of your jar.  Notice how you can use the dots on the right to locate it easily.
- VM options: These are the options for controlling the JVM.  For example, the `-Xmx1200m` sets the maximum RAM of the JVM.  I tested what I showed for your configuration.  You can separate them with spaces as you would on the command-line.
- Program arguments: These are the arguments you would feed to your program if you invoked it via the command-line as `java programName arguments`.
- Environment variables can be set with name and value via the three dots on the right and then the plus in the bottom left.  For you these would include key=jsse.enableSNIExtension and value=false.  I'm pretty confident about removing the D, but may be wrong there.  Let me know via your testing if it's wrong.
- JRE: Leave to default unless desired otherwise.
- Search sources using module's classpath: If your module is configured correctly you can leave this to `Default`.
- Before launch: Activate tool window: You can add other tasks to create cool chains of tasks.

Note you can directly run your Maven project without creating a jar first, just in case that's what you're doing. Also, the `-XX:MaxPermSize=256M` appears to be deprecated and using address `30306` caused an error when I tested, but an arbitrary `5005` did work.

Comment: 1. -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false : Should these go anywhere?

2. -Xmx1200m -XX:MaxPermSize=256M : I've added them to VM options

3. -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=30306,suspend=n : Where should I put these?

Comment: Please try the configuration in the third image and note the final paragraph of my post :)

Comment: very helpful and well written answer!

Comment: Thanks @user2407334 !